# please explain e4defrag output

Tags: command-line

can anyone please explain to me what the failure means in the following output of e4defrag run from terminal in Linux?

```
Success:            [ 353/410 ]
Failure:            [ 57/410 ]
```

this is the output after running e4defrag from the terminal, please explain what failure means in this output.
thanks in advance